# Static Site Generation of Dynamic Routes in App Router

Tags: reactjs, app-router, static-site-generation, next.js14

In Next.js 14.X App Router, it seems dynamic routes on static site generation doesn't work, which is working in Page Router. When I build the project, dynamic routes are built as server side routes.

Tried to add `export const dynamicParams = true` in the page, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.